# User plans / limit with payment in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

Has anyone done user plans / user limits with SaaS payment in MeteorJS? Did you use a specify package?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing something with `alanning:roles`?

You can set the plans/user limits but not yet the payment :-)

Comment: No roles is my backup but was looking for something that did a bit more

Comment: Thanks this might work but at the end I think I'm going to have to hard code everything

Comment: Cool~! Update us your progress if possible :-) Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could asked Ryan Glover. He built the properapp.com with Meteor and implemented user plans.

Comment: Cool he is a fine guy. I am sure he will help you. Wish you all the best.